# Disable swipe down to reload a page in Chrome browser

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, browser, chrome-for-android

While filling out an HTML form, I accidentally swiped down and lost all my filled information because the browser reloaded the page. Is it possible to deactivate this swipe down functionality?

My Android version is 4.1.2 and I'm having the Chrome latest version.

Comment: As an interim suggestion, if you are trying to scroll the page be swiping just make sure not to begin the swipe from the top of the screen downwards (given that you can't scroll past the top anyways).  I don't see an option for this in Chrome's settings.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to disable the feature in Chrome browser version 41 and above. The easiest way to disable this is to visit the `chrome://flags` in your Chrome address bar and to disable the pull to refresh effect,

```
chrome://flags (disable-pull-to-refresh-effect)
```

**Preventing the pull-to-refresh effect:**(Based on this [Chromium docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12Ay4s3NWake8Qd6xQeGiYimGJ_gCe0UMDZKwP9Ni4m8/edit?usp=sharing))

> The default action of the pull-to-refresh effect can be effectively
>   prevented by doing any of the following :
>
> - Applying “touch-action:
>     none” to touch-targeted elements, where appropriate, disabling default
>     actions (including pull-to-refresh) of the touch sequence.
> - Applying
>     “overflow-y: hidden” to the body element, using a div for scrollable
>     content if necessary.
> - preventDefault’ing some portion of the touch
>     sequence, including any of the following (in order of most disruptive
>     to least disruptive):
>
>   1. The entire touch stream (not ideal).
>   2. All top
>        overscrolling touchmoves.
>   3. The first top overscrolling touchmove.
>   4. The
>        first top overscrolling touchmove only when
>
>      - 1) the initial touchstart
>          occurred when the page y scroll offset was zero and
>      - 2) the touchmove
>          would induce top overscroll.
> - Disabling the effect locally via
>     chrome://flags (disable-pull-to-refresh-effect).
>
> Note that the pull-to-refresh effect will never activate if any
>   scrolling occurs before the overscrolling motion, e.g., if the user
>   first scrolls down, then back up, or if the page scroll offset is 0
>   but has a scrolling div that the user scrolls up before overscrolling.

**Note:**

The pull-to-refresh swipe down feature is [added to Chrome version 41.0.2272.92](http://androidcommunity.com/chrome-for-android-updated-pull-down-to-refresh-feature-added-20150312/). So any version below that won't be have the pull-to-refresh feature.

Comment: Very cool, and a nice detailed answer.

Comment: This option appears to be no longer available  at chrome//flags.